# After Nedry's hack on Jurassic Park, where have all the other staff gone?

Tags: jurassic-park

After Nedry shut down the fences and security systems of the park, stole the embryos and fled, it looks like John Hammond, Ray Arnolds, Muldoon and the tourists are the only people left on Isla Nublar. Where have all the other staff gone? E.g. the jeep driver who took Ellie back to the visitor center?

We know the one Japanese scientist went on the ship Nedry wanted to board too, but that ship was in quite a hurry, and we still see other staff with Hammond and Arnolds just after Nedry's theft. After the T-Rex's escape however, no other people seem to be there on Isla Nublar except those mentioned above, and that's confirmed when

> they're the only ones who leave Isla Nublar eventually (respectively them who survive any dinosaur attacks).

Wouldn't more security guards be needed to protect the survivors and shoot the raptors for instance?

Comment: I don't have the quotes in mind, nor time to dig out the movie, so I can't Answer.  I just recall a lot of bustle and concern about a major tropical storm coming down.  The word "evacuation" might have been used. That's why the ship was in a hurry to depart.

Comment: @Blaze There were still other staff seen just after Nedry's hack. Since the ship was in a hurry they must have left by other means. However, the park would have been far from safe for the public if you have to evacuate everyone due to a typhoon (which wouldn't have been necessary as everyone back on the island stayed safe anyway, concerning the storm).

Comment: *"Ladies and gentlemen, last shuttle to the dock leaves in approximately five minutes."* - Guess the rest of them caught the shuttle or indeed had to use other means.

Comment: Everyone else had already left. The intent was to leave to the park on "auto" for a few days until the storm passed.

Comment: @Valorum So each time a storm is coming, the entire Isla Nublar is evacuated and the dinosaurs are left alone? The typhoon wasn't that dangerous anyway, just heavy rain. There was no need to bring any supervisors off the island.

Comment: @Betternottell - I'll write an answer shortly (if no-one else does) but its supposed to be a big storm.

Comment: @Valorum Also, Mr. Arnolds told Mr. Hammond that they begin the tour "tomorrow" anew from where the first one ended. This doesn't make it seem that they intended to go back to the mainland (or to the Cinco Muertes) meanwhile, but rather stay on Isla Nublar.

Comment: @Betternottell - They were going to stay in the guest thing in what amounts to a bunker.

Comment: @Valorum Some supervisors and snipers could have stayed there too. But probably noone took into account such incident and they learned too late about what happened.